# Forcing HTTPS breaks RewriteRule in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having trouble, I have my SEO friendly urls working exactly the way that I want them.  Every time I try to force https it breaks all of my `RewriteRule`'s

```
#error redirect
ErrorDocument 404 /

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]



#rewrite pages

# Main Site
RewriteRule ^photo/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /photo.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /video.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^quote/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /quote.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /post.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^author/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /author.php?display_name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /tag.php?tag_name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /category.php?slug=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /category.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/$ /blog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /blog.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^edisto/$ /edisto.php [L]
RewriteRule ^edisto/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /edisto.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^mischief/$ /mischief.php [L]
RewriteRule ^mischief/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /mischief.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^dynamite-lady/$ /dynamite-lady.php [L]
RewriteRule ^dynamite-lady/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /dynamite-lady.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^videos/$ /videos.php [L]
RewriteRule ^videos/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /videos.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^photos/$ /photos.php [L]
RewriteRule ^photos/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /photos.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^meet-the-crew/$ /meet-the-crew.php [L]
RewriteRule ^check-ins/$ /check-ins.php [L]
RewriteRule ^404/$ /404.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I do not notice you _forcing_ https anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply redirect using `%{HTTPS}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Instead of sporting several similar rewrites, combine them into a single one:

```
RewriteRule ^(photo|videos?|quote|post|author|...)/([^/]+)/.+$ /$1.php?slug=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(blog|check-ins|videos|photos|...)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I tried your rewrite at the top of my `.htaccess` for HTTPS but It is still giving errors and this is what the Apache logs are kicking out: `Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/post (None could be negotiated).`

Comment: @JeffThomas Check if you have `MultiViews` enabled anywhere. If so, disable it.